# Does google reCAPTCHA have access to my form fields?

Tags: html, forms, security, recaptcha

Google has come up with a new reCAPTCHA,that analyse the user interaction with the form to determined if it is a bot or a real human.
I tried to find information regarding the reCAPTCHA control access to the actual form fields.
I am concern that sensitive information might rich to Google from the analysis...

Any one has any insight about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

reCAPTCHA is added to the page by a `<script>` element.

`<script>` elements load JavaScript into the page.

JavaScript in the page has access to the full DOM of the page, including the form fields and is capable of making HTTP requests to send the data to places.

By putting their script in the page, you are giving Google access to your data.

You would have to reverse engineer the script or watch the Net tab very carefully to determine if their script uses that access to send the data to their servers.

Since the script is hosted on their servers, if it doesn't send your data to Google now, it is possible for Google to change the script so it does in the future.

---

Whenever you use any JS hosted by a third party, you have to trust the third party.

Answer (score -2):

As far as i know the recaptcha does not have any knowledge about your form fields.It is only concerened with the text you are entering in the captcha and to send a response acoordingly.
Hope this helps